Using column group subtotal in calculated field formula
I am pulling data into a Table in Excel using Power Query and then presenting this in a Pivot Table.
The Pivot Table has one field included in the "Columns" area, causing distinct values in that field to be transposed into the header as columns, allowing me to sum another field but grouped by each of those values, all as normal and expected.
But now I have also grouped those distinct values into two groups and displayed a column subtotal for each group, which also works fine.
But finally, I want to add an additional column to the table, showing the Grand Total as a proportion of one of the two column subtotals, and I just cannot find a way to do this.
I've tried searching around the built-in Pivot Table functionality, but couldn't find anything. I also tried instead adding the source data table to the Data Model and using Power Pivot to create a measure to achieve this, but again, had no success.
To try and help illustrate, here's a minimal example with some dummy data in it - firstly some source data in a table:

Edit: As requested, here is the dummy source data in text form:



Project No
Customer Name
Document No
Posting Date
Account No
Amount
Department




P001
ACME Inc.
POR-001
01/01/2024
5010
£300.00
Operations


P001
ACME Inc.
POR-002
03/01/2024
5020
£100.00
Operations


P001
ACME Inc.
INV-001
05/01/2024
4010
-£500.00
Operations


P001
ACME Inc.
INV-002
08/01/2024
4010
-£200.00
Electrical


P001
ACME Inc.
INV-003
09/01/2024
4010
-£100.00
Electrical


P001
ACME Inc.
POR-003
09/01/2024
5030
£700.00
Operations


P001
ACME Inc.
INV-004
12/01/2024
4010
-£950.00
Operations


P001
ACME Inc.
POR-004
13/01/2024
5010
£150.00
Operations


P001
ACME Inc.
CRD-001
13/01/2024
4050
-£200.00
Operations


P001
ACME Inc.
INV-005
15/01/2024
4010
-£250.00
Electrical


P001
ACME Inc.
CRD-002
16/01/2024
4050
-£50.00
Electrical


P002
SO Ltd
POR-005
02/01/2024
5040
£850.00
Operations


P002
SO Ltd
INV-006
04/01/2024
4010
-£1,000.00
Electrical


P002
SO Ltd
INV-007
12/01/2024
4010
-£250.00
Electrical


P002
SO Ltd
POR-006
18/01/2024
5020
£300.00
Operations


P002
SO Ltd
INV-008
20/01/2024
4010
-£475.00
Electrical


P002
SO Ltd
POR-007
22/01/2024
5030
£250.00
Electrical


P002
SO Ltd
POR-008
25/01/2024
5010
£275.00
Operations


P002
SO Ltd
POR-009
26/01/2024
5010
£290.00
Operations


P002
SO Ltd
POR-010
26/01/2024
5030
£625.00
Electrical


P002
SO Ltd
POR-011
27/01/2024
5020
£125.00
Electrical


P002
SO Ltd
POR-012
28/01/2024
5020
£50.00
Operations


P002
SO Ltd
INV-009
29/01/2024
4010
-£2,500.00
Operations


P002
SO Ltd
CRD-003
29/01/2024
4050
-£250.00
Electrical


P002
SO Ltd
CRD-004
29/01/2024
4050
-£150.00
Operations



The full .xlsx file I've used for this example is also available to download here.
And then how my Pivot Table looks:

So my Pivot Table setup looks like this:

The "Account No2" field in the Columns area only appeared once I grouped the columns into Revenue and Cost of Sales.
So what I'm looking to achieve here is a Gross Margin % which will show on every row, regardless of what is expanded/contracted, so like this:

or like this if I collapse down to Customer:

Essentially, the Gross Margin % for Project P001 is 1000/2250 and for P002 it's 1860/4625 (and similarly for the figures shown when Department is expanded, showing the Gross Margin per Dpertment for that Project, instead of the entire Project overall), so I am trying to find a way to show a calculated field or similar which can perform this calculation and include it in my Pivot Table.
I hope someone has faced a similar problem before and can offer some suggestions! The example file I used to generate these screenshots can be downloaded here if it's helpful to have a play around with my dummy data and pivot.

To make the data useful please edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this Markdown Tables Generator.

Thanks Ron, I will do that now - although the full .xlsx is also attached if people want to download it and try to help me.

Have you considered using spill ranges instead of pivot tables? Might be better for what you are doing or is it an absoluate requirement to use a pivot table? You could create spill ranges with your unique rows/cols and then use countifs/averageifs/sumifs etc to aggregate your data rather than the pivot table?

@AndyRobertson - no, I've not come across spill ranges before - I'll do some googling and take a look, thanks.

Add two columns to your source data table.Making the formulae as follows:
Invoice Val
=IF([@Amount]<0,ABS([@Amount]),"")
PO Val
=IF([@Amount]>0,[@Amount],"")

In your pivot table add calculated fields.
=ABS(Amount)/InvoiceVal
This should give you a percentage of the absolute amount which you then need to format as percentage.


You don't actually need the PO Val column in your source data! Apologies for that.

Thanks Andy, I'll give this a try today and will accept your answer and award the bounty if it works out for me.

This works, which is great - are you able to just help me with how I can hide all of the additional columns which adding this calculated field brings into the pivot table? I just want to see the final margin per row ("Total Sum of Test" in your example) and not all of the individual "Sum of Test" columns which also appear...

I realise I could just hide them in the normal way in Excel, but the set of possible transposed columns is somewhat dynamic, so I don't think this would work.

Sorry, been away for a while. Thanks for accepting the answer, did you manage to hide what you didn't want? I think you probably just need to remove subtotals on various fields but I haven't checked this yet. Will have a quick look and get back.

HI Andy, I just went down the route of hiding in the traditional way in Excel, but if you can offer a more elegant solution, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

You should be able to add columns within power query.
After you import the data, add a custom column with the calculations you are looking for. Once you have the new column, it will be logically connected to the particular document number, and so should show up in your pivot table report.

The problem with this is that I have rows transposed into columns in the Pivot Table and it is values in those columns which I want to perform the calculation on, so these values are not available to me at the Power Query stage of fetching the data. Take a look at the dummy example I linked in the question and if you're able to implement something which works, please let me know!

@3N1GM4 which of the rows/columns are transposed?

all of the Account No columns, as per the example attached to my question and the detail given in the question.
